# Is there any software which can send pdf to email with right click

Tags: windows-7, email

I want some software where i can right click on pdf file and it sends to emial address.
i want the process of attaching attachment to email and then send it.

is there any way.

I tried [Send to Gmail](http://download.cnet.com/Send-To-GMail/3000-2242_4-10506658.html) but that was not working.

Comment: If you are using webmail (email through your we browser) then this is very difficult.  You need to install and set up an email application on your computer.

Comment: @Mokubai: Chrome can make it work for Gmail: http://gmailblog.blogspot.de/2012/02/open-email-links-directly-in-gmail.html Just wanted to mention it :)

Comment: @user1504143 Just to clarify, your requirement is not simply to be able to right click a pdf in order to attach it to an email but is more specifically that you want that pdf emailed to a preset recipient automatically without intervention.  In essence you want a right click menu that instead of "Mail recipient" as in Olivers answer you want something like "RECIPIENT NAME" and for it to send straight away.

Comment: When you say "Send to Gmail was not working". What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

I always assumed this to be in Windows 7 by default:

[image]

Otherwise, it must have been installed with Thunderbird.

Comment: but then it will open the email client and then i have to send it. i just want to send by right clicking. there is utility like send gmail which does this. but i was looking for more

Comment: @user1504143: So, you want a **different** email client to send the email? Would you mind providing a link to or the correct name of that "send gmail" application, so that I can have a look?

Comment: this is the link http://download.cnet.com/Send-To-GMail/3000-2242_4-10506658.html